# How to parse a guid from a string containing backslashes?

Tags: c#

I need to create guids from their string equivalents from a text dump that I get from the Mailchimp 1.0 export api.

The guids are all strings that contain the backslash \ character, for example here is (truncated) one of them:

```
"\"9ffd2c3-6er456ds\""
```

When I pass the guid to the following methods, nothing works when I then attempt `Guid.TryParse`.

```
string[] values = sub.Split(',');
string rawguid = values[3];
var guid = rawguid.Replace("\\", "");
var tguid = rawguid.Trim();
var sguid = rawguid.Normalize().ToString();
```

How can I properly parse these guid strings into guids?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no backslashes in your guid - those are *escaped doublequotes* inside the string : the backslash is escaping the `"` inside it. Use `.Replace("\"","")` to remove them.

Beside that - you do not have a valid GUID - there are **`r`** and a **`s`** inside - guids consist of 32 digits using only `0-9a-fA-F`.

---

Example using [Guid.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var guid = Guid.ParseExact(
            "\"ab9ffd2c3-6e456daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\"" // guid with masked " inside
            .Replace("-","")                        // remove all - for N
            .Replace("\"",""), "N");                // remove all \" as well

        Console.WriteLine( guid );
    }
}
```

to get a parsed guid:

```
 ab9ffd2c-36e4-56da-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Gem of an answer! Thank you __/\__